# Is there a dojo/Deferred adapter for es6?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm finding it difficult to write an adapter to support chaining (promise.then().catch()).  Is there dojo 1.x solution for es6 promises?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

Dojo has implemented is "own" Promise/Deferred system which is compatible even older browsers (ES3/ES5). If you need to use promises from code which relay on ES6 native implementation and interact with dojo, you could use a wrapper, where you wrap the dojo deferred objects in a ES6 promise native implementation so it can be compatible with the rest of your base code.

Below dojo related modules:

```
dojo/Deferred
dojo/when
dojo/promise
```

Comment: I think that is not as straightforward as it first seems.  The then callbacks are able to modify the deferred result.  I found it easier to break compatibility and use the dojo API.

Comment: @CoreyAlix Hi, if you think my answer was useful or informative, please do not forget to up-vote/accept it using the green tick or up arrow on its left side. Thanks and happy coding :)

Comment: I think your answer is a paraphrase of my question :)